# Calculated Column formula

Tags: sharepoint, calculated-columns

I have this question regarding creating a calculated column in SharePoint. My problem is that I need a column that will display text values in a dropdown list and once the user selects one of the text values, a number value will be assigned to each text value and will be stored in the field to be referenced by another calculated column.

So the text values would have the following values:

Major - 3
Moderate - 2
Minor - 1

Is there anyway to do this with one sharepoint column? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
=IF(SourceColumn="Major",3,IF(SourceColumn="Moderate",2,1))
```

Comment: Maybe I was incorrect in how I meant to complete my task but perhaps I don't need to use a calculated column in SharePoint. I'm not sure how to do this but what I would like to do is create a column that would appear to the user as a drop down list but the column would store a value that I would assign to each text value. This column would then be used in a calculated column that would use the numerical value to make a calculation and I think this is what your formula accomplishes. Do you know how I would create a column that would record a number but display as a drop down list?

Comment: Sure. You can create a simple numeric column and then customize EditItem.aspx with SharePoint Designer. It is pure HTML, just add simple drop down... it requires some skill if you haven't tried that already.

Comment: Do you know of a good resource that shows how to do this type of thing? I'm just not sure how to make those changes. I have SharePoint Designer but I'm not sure how to make those changes to a list form web part. Would I have to change the list form web part to custom list form? Thanks for all your help by the way. I couldn't find any good resources anywhere on my problem.

Comment: Start with this one: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/HA101191111033.aspx